# Why is PHP handling the dangling else differently?

Tags: php, syntax

I have this piece of code:

```
$a = false;
if ($a) 
    echo 'A'; if (false) echo 'B';
  else echo 'C';
```

The `else` statement appears to changes "belongship" depending on the value of `$a`. If it's `true`, it seems to interpret it as:

```
if ($a) 
{
    echo 'A';
    if (false) 
    {
        echo 'B';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'C';
    }
}
```

And prints `AC`. But if `$a = false`, it seems to be interpreting it as:

```
if ($a) 
{
    echo 'A';
    if (false) 
    {
        echo 'B';
    } 
}
else 
{
    echo 'C';
}
```

And prints `C`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: There is no ambiguous code in your first example

Comment: Questions like this are why people should use braces in all but the simplest situations. (and even then in my opinion)

Comment: Stop and think about this from a state perspective and it becomes obvious as to why your two snippets (the ones that have {}) are happening.  That's not how PHP is actually seeing it, that just happens to be logically equivalent to the flow of how PHP is seeing it (conditional on $a).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first code reads as

```
$a = false;
if ($a) {
    echo 'A';
}

if (false) {
    echo 'B';
}
else {
    echo 'C';
}
```

When you do not use braces, only the next statement (statement, not line) gets executed as part of that control structure.  It is not ambiguous as this behaviour is clearly defined in the programming language.

Comment: I see. I confused myself by focusing on something else. Genius.

Answer (score 4):

```
$a = false;
if ($a) 
    echo 'A'; if (false) echo 'B';
  else echo 'C';
```

equals to

```
$a = false;

if ($a) echo 'A';

if (false) echo 'B'; else echo 'C';
```

because `if` control structure accepts a statement as a body, see: http://php.net/if

And `echo 'A';` is that statement. So the next `if` is treated as independent piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

Both sets of results are consistent with the single interpretation:

```
if ($a) 
{
    echo 'A';
}
if (false) 
{
    echo 'B';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'C';
}
```

So I would guess that's what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Helps if you get the indentation correct i.e.

```
$a = false; 

if ($a) echo 'A';

if (false) echo 'B'; 
else echo 'C';
```

a - false, result is C
a - true, result AC